# Create variable names based on the elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, casting

I'm relatively new to coding in python so go easy on me.

I want to create integer variables with the names of these variables based off elements of a string array and set them all to zero to start with (in order to save me manually coding 20 variables out). The string array is shown below.

```
filterKeywords = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Apple',
  'Google', 'Amazon', 'EBay', 'Diageo',
  'General Motors', 'General Electric', 'Telefonica', 'Rolls Royce',  
  'Walmart', 'HSBC', 'BP',
  'Investec', 'WWE', 'Time Warner', 'Santander Group']
```

I don't want the variable names to be exactly the name of the element in the `array`, however, I want the variable names to contain the elements from the `array`, for example: for the `string` element 'apple' I want my variable name to be 'applePositive'.  I have tried to implement this and here it is below (I'm not sure if it is the correct format or not).

```
for word in filterKeywords:
    [word + "Positive"] = 0
```

I'm getting a "cannot assign to operator" error with this and I've tried also to cast it to an `int` but it doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do not do that. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Seconded. Creating variable names like that is not a good idea, nor is it possible with spaces in the strings. A dictionary would be more suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
vars = {}
for word in filterKeywords:
    vars[word + "Positive"] = 0
```

Then use it however you want, for example, say, `print vars["applePositive"]`.

You can access all your "names" with `vars.keys()`

You can do further computations on all the items too

```
for word, value in vars.iteritems():
    # do something
    print word, value
```

or

```
for i in vars:
    print i, vars[i]
```

And if at some point, you get suspicious if "applePositive" is in your dict and has a value, you can do `'applePositive' in vars`, which will return either `True` or `False`.

And then if you decide to add 1 to the values of only Facebook and Apple, you can do that too

```
for i in ['applePositive', 'facebookPositive']:
    if i in vars:
        vars[i] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! As I said I'm relatively new to this so ill implement that into my code now

Comment: `applePositive in vars` is enough ... no need to extract the keys.

Comment: also ... when looping over the items, you might want to use the iterator version => `for word, value in var.iteritems():`

Comment: @JulienSpronck agreed again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a  dic comprehension to put each value to a dictionary

```
filterKeywords = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Apple']
d = {k + "positive":0 for k in filterKeywords}
```

Which outputs:

```
{'IBMpositive': 0, 'Yahoopositive': 0, 'Microsoftpositive': 0, 'Facebookpositive': 0, 'Applepositive': 0}
```